# Prevent div from scrolling on top when page inside home page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am new to javascript and I am working on my project. I have two pages here, the first one is home.php and here is the code that calls data.php and refreshes it every 3 seconds:

```
<div id="show"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function reload()
                    {
                        $("#show").load("data.php");
                    }
                    $(function() {
                        setInterval(reload, 3000);
                    });</script>
```

In data.php, here is my code:

```
<div class = "table-container" id = "table-container">
echo '<table class = "track" name = "allData" id = "allData">           
                                <tr style">
                                    <th> Device ID </th>
                                    <th> Name </th>
                                    <th> Date and Time </th>
                                    <th> latitude </th>
                                    <th> longitude </th>
                                    <th> Contact Number </th>
                                    <th> Age </th>
                                    <th> Track </th>
                                    <th> Status </th>
                                </tr>';

                                $sql = "SELECT d.deviceID, CONCAT(u.lastName, ', ', u.firstName) AS Name, t.dateTime, t.latitude, t.longitude, u.contactNumber, u.age, t.status
                                    FROM tbltracking as t 
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbldevicemaster as d 
                                    ON t.deviceID = d.deviceID
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblusers as u 
                                    ON d.userID = u.userID
                                    ORDER BY dateTime;";
                                $result = $conn-> query($sql);
                                $number = $result -> num_rows;
                                if ($result-> num_rows > 0) 
                                {
                                    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) 
                                    {
                                        echo 
                                        "<tr><td>"
                                            . $row ["deviceID"] 
                                            ."</td><td class = 'name'>"
                                            . $row ["Name"] 
                                            ."</td><td>"
                                            . $row ["dateTime"] 
                                            ."</td><td class = 'latitude'>"
                                            . $row ["latitude"] 
                                            ."</td><td class = 'longitude'>"
                                            . $row ["longitude"]
                                            ."</td><td>"
                                            . $row ["contactNumber"] 
                                            ."</td><td>"
                                            . $row ["age"]
                                            ."</td><td>"
                                            .'<button type = "button" class = "a"> Select</button>'
                                            ."</td><td>" .$row["status"]
                                            ."</td></tr>";

                                    }
                                    echo "</table>";
                                    echo "</div>";
```

Here is the CSS for the table container:

```
.table-container
    {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 170px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

So yes, at home.php, the data.php window can be showed inside the div id "show" and it is being refreshed every 3 seconds so that the page runs the query again. The problem is, when I am at home.php, whenever I try to scroll the table and it refreshes, the scroll bar goes at the top.

Like I said, I am relatively new to programming so can anyone help me out?

I also tried another code which works when I am ONLY at data.php page and refreshing the page manually. The method is storing it to localstorage. Here is part of the code at data.php:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
localStorage.setItem("scrollPositon", document.querySelector(".table-container").scrollTop);
});


window.addEventListener("load", () => {
document.querySelector(".table-container").scrollTop = localStorage.getItem("scrollPositon") || 0;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why not use ajax to dynamically load your data from data.php? the set interval refresh basically refreshes the page hence the scroll goes back to the top.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way you can reload data.php content and keep your scroll position, the issue is due to your table height, which is refreshed every 3 seconds, so what you need to do is take your table-container and table tags away from data.php like this:

(inside **home.php**)

```
<div class="table-container">
  <table class="track" name="allData" id="show"> <!-- ID: show -->
  </table>
</div>

<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
    $("#show").load("data.php"); //Load the content into the div
}), 3000);

</script>
```

And inside your **data.php** :

```
echo '<tr style">
  <th> Device ID </th>
   ...
   ...
   etc..
     ...
     ...
     ."</td><td>" .$row["status"]
     ."</td></tr>";
    }
```

This will keep your scroll position each time is reloaded, if you want to show data.php content somewhere else, you have to add table-container and the table tag too just like I showed you in home.php.